# avoid many redirections when forcing https and www in front of the url

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, nginx

I have a website that I'm deploying to a server with https enabled. So my client's  requirements are as follow:

1. Force https.
2. Keep www in the url, in order to get urls as https://www.example.com, not https://exambple.com so the 3ws are forced too.

I used this rule on the .htaccess file in order to get the desired effects:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/es/$1/ [R=301,L]
```

But when testing page speed using [PageSpeed Insights](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights) I get a poor Server Response Time of 1s. And debugging using Chrome Developer Tools I see that the response time of the website after the last redirection is about 300ms so, the redirections are increasing the response time.

**So, my question is, how can I force https and www in front of the url while minimizing redirects?**

Answer (score 1):

Try doing it like this:

Force SSL:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Force WWW:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use below rules which will append www and https with your URL.

```
RewriteEngine On

# Ensure www.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]


# Ensure https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```